# Inverse of a matrix defined on C

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

Let $ A $ be a real symmetric matrix and form the matrix
\begin{equation}
R(z)=(zI - A)^{-1}
\end{equation}
for complex values of z, whenever it is defined. Prove: The elements of R(z) are quotients of two polynomials in z whose denominators have zeros of at most first order.

Comment: $R(z)$ is obviously not defined on only finite set of real numbers, which are eigenvalues of $A$. But does it help?

Comment: Is that $I$ supposed to be blackboard bold?

Comment: Argument 1: regard $z\mathbb{I} - A$ as a matrix whose entries are rational functions in $z$. Argument 2: $M^{-1} = (\det M)^{-1}\cdot \operatorname{adj}M$ (or $\operatorname{adj}M^T$, depends on how you define it).

Comment: But it doesn't imply that denominators have zeros of at most first order, does it?

Comment: It does, a polynomial (other than $0$) has only finitely man zeros (counting multiplicity, the number of zeros equals the degree), and there are only finitely many polynomials in the matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A being real symetric, you can diagonalize it in an orthonormal basis : $A=P^T D P$ where D is diagonal $D=diag(d_1,\dots,d_n)$.

Then the expression of R(z) is then straightforward (with $z\neq d_1,\dots d_n$) and you can deduce the propertie you want from here :
$$[R(z)]_{ij}=\sum_{k}\frac{P_{ki}P_{kj}}{z-d_k}=\frac{Q(z)}{\prod_k (z-d_k)}$$